# If column is substring of another dataframe column set value

Tags: pandas, numpy

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['OK340820.1','OK340821.1'],'Length':[50000,67000]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['OK340820','OK340821'],'Length':[np.nan,np.nan]})
```

If df2.Key is a substring of df1.Key, set Length of df2 as value of Length in df1

I tried doing this:

```
df2['Length']=np.where(df2.Key.isin(df1.Key.str.extract(r'(.+?(?=\.))')), df1.Length, '')
```

But it's not returning the matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to extract the string, then map the values:

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df2['Key']))

s = pd.Series(df1['Length'].values, index=df1['Key'].str.extract(f'({pattern})', expand=False))

df2['Length'] = df2['Key'].map(s)
```

Updated `df2`:

```
        Key  Length
0  OK340820   50000
1  OK340821   67000
```

Or with a `merge`:

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df2['Key']))

(df2.drop(columns='Length')
    .merge(df1, how='left', left_on='Key', suffixes=(None, '_'),
           right_on=df1['Key'].str.extract(f'({pattern})', expand=False))
    .drop(columns='Key_')
)
```

Alternative if the Key in `df1` is always in the form `XXX.1` and removing the `.1` is enough:

```
df2['Length'] = df2['Key'].map(df1.set_index(df1['Key'].str.extract('([^.]+)', expand=False))['Length'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Map `df2.Key` to a "prepared" `Key` values of `df1`:

```
df2['Length'] = df2.Key.map(dict(zip(df1.Key.str.replace(r'\..+', '', regex=True), df1.Length)))
```

---

```
In [45]: df2
Out[45]: 
        Key  Length
0  OK340820   50000
1  OK340821   67000
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df2.update(df1.assign(Key = df1['Key'].str.extract('(.*)\.')))
```

Output:

```
        Key   Length
0  OK340820  50000.0
1  OK340821  67000.0
```